# Auto update page content without page reloading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is the logic behind the updating of a cell in google sheet where other users can see what is changing to the data in real-time?

I have this data in a table where in user can mark a row as matched/unmatched.

What I wanted to do is for example:
*When the **user1** mark row# 1 of the table as **matched**, that row should be updated as well to other users browser. In short, in every action of a user, it should be visible to other.

Any idea or help on how I could start it?

UPDATE: I think using ajax would be possible. But I am still looking for the logic.

Comment: ajax or maybe websockets are probably being used.

Comment: [PounchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) may help you